# View Cube Event

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I am searching for an event that gets fired when the user interacts with the view cube.

Use Case: I have drawn markups in the viewer (Using markupscore extension) and set the default interaction with the viewer on. So whenever a user rotates the view with the help of view cube I want to remove the markups, for which I need the event that is getting fired when the user interacts with view cube.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no events available specific to reflect user interaction with View cube - events like `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT`, `RENDER_PRESENTED_EVENT` etc would get fired whenever navigation and/or rendering takes place, regardless of what the user does with the viewcube ...

I'd propose to Engineering to consider implementing specific events for viewcube interaction ...

In the meantime as workaround you can try to capture the mouse events by adding a listener for the viewcube UI element, something like:

```
const viewCube = Unfortunately there's no events available specific to reflect user interaction with View cube - `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT` would get fired whenever

I'd propose to Engineering to consider

In the meantime as workaround you can try to capture the mouse events by adding a listener for the viewcube UI element, something like:
```

NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.VIEW_CUBE_CREATED_EVENT, ()=>{  // wait till viewcube is ready ...
const viewCube = NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi')
viewCube.container.addEventListener('click', handler ...) // or work on child elements through the container
//...
})